# Column ' ' in field list is ambigious

Tags: mysql, sql

i recieve an error

> column expeertID in field list is ambiguous

im not sure how to fix this

```
INSERT INTO cv(expertID)
SELECT expertID 
FROM experts
INNER JOIN cv ON experts.expertID = cv.expertID;
```

Comment: HINT: Which `expertID` - the one from `experts` or the one from `cv` table?

Comment: Remove the ambiguity.

Comment: You have `SELECT expertID` but you didn`t specify which expertID you want.

Comment: It seems a little odd that you would want to insert into cv whilst at the same time select from it. Presumably you only want to insert an expert if he/she already exists in cv , but what if he/she doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below - you need to add `tablename`,  as `expertID column` exists in both tables

```
INSERT INTO cv(expertID)
SELECT experts.expertID 
FROM experts
INNER JOIN cv ON experts.expertID = cv.expertID;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need specify the `column name` with `tablename` from which table you want to display or `insert` data whatever you want :

```
INSERT INTO cv(expertID)
     SELECT e.expertID 
     FROM experts e INNER JOIN 
          cv 
          ON e.expertID = cv.expertID;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!

I have used table aliases and then explicitly mentioned the alias with column in select list. Now expertID in select is from experts table rather than ambiguous one.

```
INSERT INTO cv(expertID)
SELECT e.expertID 
FROM experts e
INNER JOIN cv  c ON e .expertID = c.expertID;
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly you've changed and why that is neccessary

Comment: I have used table aliases and then explicitly mentioned the alias with column in select list. Now expertID in select is from experts table rather than ambiguous one.

Comment: Please add such explanation to the answer itself, not to the comment section